# How to change a single button color in a list - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm having problems trying to change the color of a button when the user select an option. How can I pick the index selected upon click and change its color?

Thanks in advance
I added my code and the screenshot below.

```
  List<dynamic> getChoices() {
    var choices = []; //
    for (int i = 0; i < choicesText.length; i++) {
      var eachChoice = choicesText[i]['name'];

      var newChoice = Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text(
              eachChoice,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              //The user picked this button.
              userChoice = eachChoice;
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
      choices.add(newChoice);
    }
    return choices;
  }
```

[Current screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXeTU.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `var` and set a widget, I hope it works for you

```
List<dynamic> getChoices() {
        var choices = []; //
        for (int i = 0; i < choicesText.length; i++) {
          var eachChoice = choicesText[i]['name'];

      var colorChoice = if (eachChoice  = 1) return Colors.red else return  Colors.red
    
          var newChoice = Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                color: colorChoice,
                child: Text(
                  eachChoice,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  //The user picked this button.
                  userChoice = eachChoice;
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
          choices.add(newChoice);
        }
        return choices;
      }
```